# ActiveStorage in views/rendering

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I dont understand well of active storage documentation. I am using `<%= image_tag current.user.avatar.variant(resize: "600x400") %>` this in view but so slow in rendering while calling 10 images in index or show from s3. What is difference of variant and service_url? I just want to load images faster in rendering with caching. what are the options?